# Delayed Jobs leaking memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, memory-leaks, delayed-job

I'm  using [collectiveidea's delayed_job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) with my Ruby on Rails app (v2.3.8), and running about 40 background jobs with it on an 8GB RAM Slicehost machine (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Apache 2).

Let's say I ssh into my server with no workers running. When I do `free -m`, I'm see I'm generally using about 1GB of RAM out of 8. Then after starting the workers and waiting about a minute for them to be utilized by the code, I'm up to about 4GB. If I come back in an hour or two, I'll be at 8GB and into the swap memory, and my website will be generating 502 errors.

So far I've just been killing the workers and restarting them, but I'd rather fix the root of the problem. Any thoughts? Is this a memory leak? Or, as a friend suggested, do I need to figure out a way to run garbage collection?

Comment: It sounds like a memory leak, but it can be in your code that is run by deleayed_job, it must not be in delayed_job. some code to review could help.

Comment: also keep in mind, that 1.9 and 1.8 will never give memory back to the OS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just about every time someone asks about this, the problem is in their code. Try using one of the available profiling tools to find where your job is leaking. ( https://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof or similar.)

Triggering GC at the end of each job will reduce your max memory usage at the cost of thrashing your throughput. It won't stop Ruby from bloating to the max size required by any individual job, however, since Ruby can't free memory back to the OS. I don't recommend taking this approach.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, Delayed::Job 3.0 leaks memory in Ruby 1.9.2 if your models have serialized attributes. (I'm in the process of researching a solution.)

Here's someone who seemed to have solved it, http://spacevatican.org/2012/1/26/memory-leak-in-yaml-on-ruby-1-9-2

Here's the issue from Delayed::Job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/336